# What's the difference between dd into a file and dd into a physical disk

Tags: linux, dd, openwrt

The size "openwrt-19.07.6-x86-64-combined-squashfs.img" image is 20MB. If I change the file name to "openwrt.raw", I can import it into virt-manager and boot into the system.  But the root partiton "/" has no space.

If I dd the "openwrt-19.07.6-x86-64-combined-squashfs.img" into a USB drive, and then dd the USB drive to a new file, import the outfile into virt-manager and boot into the system, the root partition has the size of "256MB".

```
dd if=openwrt-19.07.6-x86-64-combined-squashfs.img of=/dev/sde
dd if=/dev/sde of=./openwrt_with_256MB_root_partition.raw
```

The size of "openwrt_with_256MB_root_partition.raw" is the same as the USB drive. But if I use the following command:

```
dd if=openwrt-19.07.6-x86-64-combined-squashfs.img of=/openwrt.raw
```

the output file is of the same size as the input file. I understand that this action is pointless. But can someone explain what makes the 256MB root partition available when I dd it into the USB drive? Is there a way to create an image file with the 256MB root space without the need of the physical USB drive or other disks?

Comment: you may want to read up on SquashFS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dunno what OpenWRT does nowadays.

However, what you are doing is simply adding some garbage data at the file end. Because the file size ends up being the device size inside the virtual machine, it’s easy to understand the result.

You can also use `truncate`:

```
truncate -s256M openwrt-19.07.6-x86-64-combined-squashfs.img
```

Strictly speaking, this is not the same, because it results in a sparse file, but it’s much faster and good enough.

To get the exact same, you actually need to write some data to the file, like this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=236 >> openwrt-19.07.6-x86-64-combined-squashfs.img
```

You can also use advanced flags in `dd`. 256 - 20 = 236

Another tool related to this is `fallocate`.

---

**Update**: Looking at the image, it’s like this:

```
$ fdisk -l openwrt-19.07.6-x86-generic-combined-squashfs.img
Disk openwrt-19.07.6-x86-generic-combined-squashfs.img: 19.5 MiB, 20450816 bytes, 39943 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf1f0223e

Device                                             Boot Start    End Sectors  Size Id Type
openwrt-19.07.6-x86-generic-combined-squashfs.img1 *      512  33279   32768   16M 83 Linux
openwrt-19.07.6-x86-generic-combined-squashfs.img2      33792 558079  524288  256M 83 Linux
```

(Note the “size” column.)

The second partition is supposed to contain the compressed read-only root image *and* a read-write F2FS area, no idea how that works. Maybe it’s resized on first boot or something.